# Spring Kafka: JsonDeserializer doesn't pick up TRUSTED_PACKAGE config

Tags: spring-kafka

I just want to check if it's known behavior or I'm doing something wrong.

I configuring producer and consumer with custom type mapping using `JsonDeserializer`.

Consumer fails with

```sh
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition ticket-1 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'createTicket' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
```

Consumer factory config

```java
props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
props.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "createTicket:com.example.application.domain.command.CreateTicket, createTicketCommand:com.example.application.domain.command.CreateTicketCommand");
```

Producer factory config

```java
props.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS,
              "createTicket:com.example.application.domain.command.CreateTicket, createTicketCommand:com.example.application.domain.command.CreateTicketCommand");
```

I tested with stable and M3 versions. 
Full runnable example https://github.com/gAmUssA/spring-kafka-question-from-chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you actually don't configure the `JsonDeserializer`.

`JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS` are to be passed to `JsonDeserializer` directly, not to `ConsumerFactory`. Your code should look like

```java
        JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        Map<String, Object> deserProps = new HashMap<>();
        deserProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS,
                "createTicket:com.example.application.domain.command.CreateTicket, createTicketCommand:com.example.application.domain.command.CreateTicketCommand");

//mind this `false` -- they have different modes for key and value deserializers
        jsonDeserializer.configure(deserProps, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                jsonDeserializer);
```

(On my machine, it works without any `TRUSTED_PACKAGES` setting)

Comment: Right; the properties are only applied when Kafka creates the deserializer; when you add them in the constructor they must be pre-configured. Since you've provided `VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG` (and KEY...) you can omit the deserializer from the factory constructor and let Kafka instantiate them.

Comment: You can also do all the configuration in application.properties (or yml). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka-extra-props